# I want to hide tax price details in order_email_template.How to do it in Magento-2.1?

Tags: magento-2.1, price, tax, order-email

I want to hide tax details from `order_email_template` in **Magento-2.1**. For comment this code in `\vendor\magento\module-sales\view\frontend\layout\sales_order_email_items.xml:`

```
<block class="Magento\Tax\Block\Sales\Order\Tax" name="tax" template="order/tax.phtml">
    <action method="setIsPlaneMode">
        <argument name="value" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
    </action>
</block>
```

I want to override it. Please help me to override this file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Core file override steps:

**Step1:** First copy core file `sales_order_email_items.xml` & past in your theme at location

> app/design/frontend///Magento_Sales/layout/

**Step : 2** Add Remove block code in file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Email Order Items List" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="tax" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Step: 3** After run below commands

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: I will run same steps,but it is not working.

Comment: Updates ans pls check & let me know

Comment: Please note that the file to modify in Magento 2.3 is sales_email_order_items.xml

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to the best answer:
That solution may not be good.
Magento calculates subtotal and taxes. When you remove block from layout it will not update totals.
see `\Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals::_beforeToHtml`
`$child->initTotals();`
So the subtotal may be decreased on tax amount, and will present a netto price.
You'd better use this approach to avoid unexpected behavior.

```
<referenceBlock name="tax" display="false"/>
```

The subtotal will be processed, but the block will not be rendered.

For more info see:

`\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock::getChildHtml`
`\Magento\Framework\View\Layout::renderElement`

Comment: Your solution suits perfectly to my requirements. Thank you.